# How to apply security patch in SharePoint 2010 without upgrading to cumulative update?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Microsoft releases security bulletin every month which also include SharePoint vulnerabilities.

We have many sites running on my SharePoint 2010 instance, and if we apply cumulative update according to Microsoft release note, every months, so there will be interruption on running sites.

Kindly share your thought on applying security fixes in SharePoint product without upgrading to cumulative update, so that we can assure uninterrupted service on running sites with latest security patch installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can apply the security-only update but it’ll require the same downtime as a CU
2. Yes. SP2010 is in security-only support. That said, security updates aren’t cumulative. CUs are. So unless you’re applying these security updates every month, it’d be best to stick with the CUs.